# Multiple og:image for Facebook

Tags: facebook

I've actually been searching on this site for the answer to this question for quite some time.
Looking for a way to 'echo/print' multiple og:images for facebook.
What I have here used only 'the_post_thumbnail'

```
function fb_image() {
if (is_single()) {
    global $post;
    $feature_image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($feature_image);
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {
            $image_url = $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
?>

<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" />
<?php }
add_action('wp_head', 'fb_image');
```

Comment: where are the images coming from? in what context do you want them added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out with

```
function postimage($size = 'thumbnail', $qty = -1) 
{
    if (is_single() && !is_home() && !wp_attachment_is_image()) {
    global $post;$images = get_children(array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'posts_per_page' => $qty,
    'post_mime_type' => 'image')
);    if ( $images ) {
        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $attachmenturl = wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID);
            $attachmentimage = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, $size );
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="'.$attachmenturl.'"/>';
        }
    } else {
        echo "No Image";
    }
}
}    
add_action('wp_head', 'postimage');
```